# Capturing Hibernate Validator message text in Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jetty

I am working on a REST api using Spring-MVC and json. I running my automatic tests using Jetty and an in-memory database. I want to test that posting an invalid domain object gives me the error message from the `@NotEmpty` annotation. But all I get is the default Jetty 400 Bad Request page.

I have a domain class with some validation:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Name is a required field")
    private String name;

    /* getters, setters */
}
```

Here's the controller

```
@Controller
public class CompanyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/company", 
        method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes = "application/json")
    public void createCompany(
        @Valid @RequestBody final Company company,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {

        //persist company
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
        response.setHeader("location", "/company/" + company.getId());
    }
}
```

How can I get the value `"Name is a required field"` returned as part of the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public void exceptionHandler(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, 
                     final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    for (final ObjectError objectError : ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
        response.getWriter().append(objectError.getDefaultMessage()).append(".");
    }
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3.2 variant using ControllerAdvice and ResponseEntityExceptionHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> 
    handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException e,
                                 HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status,
                                 WebRequest request) {
        BindingResult bindingResult = e.getBindingResult();
        ArrayList<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (ObjectError error : bindingResult.getGlobalErrors()) {
            errors.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        for (FieldError error : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
            errors.add(
              String.format("%s %s", error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage())
            );
        }
        return handleExceptionInternal(e, StringUtils.join(errors, ", "),
                headers, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `BindingResult` to your handler method.  That object will automatically add the results to the `Model`, which can then be easily accessed from the Spring Forms taglib.

Comment: That's just the order of the objects in the handler's method signature - I've had that issue before.  All you need to do is have them in a specific order (`BindingResult` then `Model`) and the problem goes away.

Comment: as per my original post, I am not using a model, nor spring forms taglib.

Comment: Why not?  Is there a particular reason?  The `Model` object is intrinsic to Spring MVC...?

Comment: atrain's resolution works for me, no "BAD REQUEST" anymore